# SQL MDS Synchronization

Tags: sql-server, master-data-services

We have following question about the SQL Master Data Service:

1. We have already integrated different client data to MDS with the help MS Excel plugin, now we want to push back updated or new added record to source database. is it possible do using MDS?
2. Do we have any background sync process to which automatically sync data to and from subscriber and MDS?

Answer (score 1):

Create subscription views in MDS.  Then you can leverage SSIS to pull the data from MDS using the subscription view and merging it into the source database.

Used in conjunction with Business Rules in MDS, the ETL can be coded to only query for "validated" members in MDS.  This allows for a nice separation of concerns so the ETL doesn't have to be overly complex with data it needs to retrieve from MDS>